# Access the child value in JSON Objects react native

Tags: json, object, react-native

I have this function to fetch the user data such in the code below.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        user_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.user_id, 
        user: null 
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.loadUserDetail()
}

loadUserDetail(){
    AccountController.loadUserDetail(this.state.user_id).then(data=>{
        if(data.status == true){
            this.setState({ user: data.user })
        }
    })
}
```

From the `loadUserDetail()` function, I set the user data in a state and the `this.state.user` result is as follow :

```
{ company_name: 'Universal Sdn Bhd', address: 'test', company_desc: 'test' }
```

So I'm trying to display these data in my render() by directly specifying the object like `this.state.user.company_name` but it doesn't work.

Here is how my rendering looked like :

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{ this.state.user.company_name }</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

By displaying the data like in the code, it throws me this error

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.user.company_name')

I'm able to display the data if I store every specific value in a state after fetching the data in the `loadUserDetail()` function but if let say I have a lot of data in my array then I have to set every each of them in a state and I want to avoid doing so.

Comment: FWIW: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `render` needs to allow for the fact that it can be called when `this.state.user` is `null` and show an appropriate display for that case, since your component will not have the `user` until/unless the asynchronous operation completes. For instance:

```
render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            {user
            ?  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{ user.company_name }</Text>
            :  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontStyle: 'italic' }}>loading</Text>
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

If you don't want your component to show a pending state for when it doesn't have `user`, the call to load the user should be in the parent component instead, and it should only render the child when the user is known (passing it as props).

---

Side note: Inline `style` is generally a maintenance hassle. Consider using classes instead.

Side note 2: Presumably, `loadUserDetail` can fail. You should have a `catch` handler on it to deal with the failure.